# Probability of $(A^c \mbox{ and }B^c)$

Tags: probability

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $P(A) = 0.2$ and $P(B) = 0.5$.  What is the value of $P(A^c \cap B^c)$?

So my thought process to this was that, since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint meaning nothing is intersecting. Wouldn't this value be $1 - P(A) + P(B)$? Since $A$ and $B$ both share complements?

Comment: Try $1-P(A)-P(B)$. Note that $A$, $B$, and $A^c\cap B^c$ together fill out all possibilites.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen wait wouldn't 1-P(A)-P(B) be the same as 1-(P(a)+P(b))? Could you explain a little about how A^c and B ^ c fill out all possibilities?

Comment: @user125627 Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, their intersection is empty, so $P(A \cap B) = 0$.  Then, $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$.  Finally, we have $P(A^c \cap B^c) = 1 - P(A \cup B) = 1 - P(A) - P(B)$, which is the same as $1 - (P(A) + P(B))$

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right (though be careful, it's 1-(P(A)+P(B)) and not 1-P(A)+P(B)). If you need to show how it is right, you can use d'Morgan's law on that phrase and then you will be able to get the ^c out, and get it to the expression you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you had used parentheses, then you'd be correct: $$P(A^c \cap B^c) = 1 -\Big(P(A) + P(B)\Big) = 1 - P(A) - P(B)$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can use de Morgan's law here:
$$A^C \cap B^C = (A\cup B)^C$$
and so
$$\begin{align*}
P(A^C \cap B^C)& = P((A\cup B)^C) = 1-P(A\cup B) \\
& \stackrel{A, B\text{ disjoint}}= 1-(P(A)+P(B)) = 1-P(A)-P(B)
\end{align*}$$